# XMLSigner - sign multiple references

Tags: python, xml, cryptography, digital-signature, xml-signature

I'm developing a digital signature system and I have a question about the XMLSigner library. I could not find my answer by looking at documentation, so I'm gonna ask here.

I have a XML file, which I need to sign it and I have more than a reference, but there's a problem: they don't have an ID specifying for a reference. The XML that I need to sign is something like:

```
<AppHdr>
        <Fr>
            <FIId>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>00038166</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </FinInstnId>
            </FIId>
        </Fr>
        (more content...)
</AppHdr>
<Document>
    (more content...)
</Document>
```

I've extracted both AppHdr and Document, and made the signature using each one, and my idea was to put them together later in another xml file, already canonicalized and encrypted, using:

```
signed_app_hdr = XMLSigner(method=methods.enveloped, signature_algorithm='rsa-sha256',
                               digest_algorithm='sha256',
                               c14n_algorithm=
                               "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"). \
            sign(et_app_hdr, key=rsa_key)

signed_document_info = XMLSigner(signature_algorithm='rsa-sha256',
                                digest_algorithm='sha256',
                                c14n_algorithm=
                                "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"). \
        sign(et_document, key=rsa_key)
```

The digital signature output (padronized by an institution that I'm sending the message), requires that

```
<Reference URI="">
```

to reference the `<AppHdr>`
And

```
<Reference>
```

to reference the `<Document>`

There's also a `<KeyInfo>`, that is referenced by an id (no issues in this case). I'm just using `sign(et_key_info, key=rsa_key, reference_uri='key-info-id')` to reference it.

So, my question is: how do I do to reference the AppHdr and Document in the `reference_uri`? Is it possible? When I just leave `reference_uri = None` (by default), it just creates `<Reference URI="">`, which would be no problem for the AppHdr. And for the document? What should I do? Could I create an artificial ID for them and remove later? Idk if it would have implications in cryptography.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Fernando, did you manage to solve this?